# Getting data from new row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, pdo

I wrote code to insert new record in MySql table. Is there any way I can get the row `id` which was inserted without making a new query?

```
try {

    $NEWData = $DBH->prepare("
    INSERT INTO boge 
        (name, grade, school, made, type) 
        VALUES (:name, :grade, :school, NOW(), '2')"
    );

    $NEWData->bindParam(':name', $navn); // Erik
    $NEWData->bindParam(':grade', $skid); // 12
    $NEWData->bindParam(':school', $klasseId); // 1 - school have an id

    // wants to get the new rows id
    $NEWData->execute();


} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();

}
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: ```$DBH->lastInsertId()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lastInsertId might have slight issues for high traffic site.
This is a more efficient solution:

```
// wants to get the new rows id
$insert = $NEWData->execute();
$lastId = $insert->insertId();
```

This enables you get the correct insert id with the greatest precision.

Comment: Sorry but i get 500 error then i run the code, it dont give me a PDO error

Comment: I didn't write code for anything. I just corrected a guys error. You may need to ask a new question and post the link here so i can fix your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdo function lastInsertId 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Also in some DB engines you can add "returning id" after your INSERT INTO, but the PDO ways will always work.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$last_insert_id = $DBH->lastInsertId();
echo "<p>$last_insert_id</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :-D